# Previously unsigned App from Applescript (now signed) quits working

Tags: macos, applescript, code-signing

I made an Applescript app by exporting a *.scpt-File to an app and signing it with a valid cert. Later I needed to change the Info.plist by opening the package, because I had to add a key for using a custom protocol handler. The app quits working.

```
codesign --verbose --verify /Applications/Toolkit.app // in terminal shows
/Applications/Toolkit.app: invalid Info.plist (plist or signature have been modified)
```

Indeed I changed both, but what would be the correct way to revalidate the app?

Comment: That's the main purpose of code-signing: Modifying the binary invalidates the app. You have to code-sign it again.

Comment: I know, but when I export the scpt to app, my needed changes to Info.plist aren´t available anymore. How can I achieve that in Applescript

Comment: How about **saving** the script as application, then reopen it in Script Editor/Debugger, modify the Info.plist and then **export** it.

Comment: Yes, I tried that in the meanwhile. Thx, it works

Comment: I have been a little bit hasty, but in fact this does not work. After exporting it in step2 Info.plist is reset to default? Just the signature is alright.

Answer (score 0):

Here´s what I was looking for:

```
xattr -cr /Applications/Toolkit.app // cleans the package
codesign -s "name of your identity" -f -v /Applications/Toolkit.app // resigns with your identity
```

After that the output of "codesign --verbose --verify /Applications/Toolkit.app" is:

```
Toolkit.app: valid on disk
Toolkit.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Regards